# How do I get the current week start date and end date in ksh

Tags: shell, date

I want to get the current week start date and end date in shell scripting.

example:

for the current week

start date is **041015**
end date is **101015**

Comment: Are you using Linux or some version of Unix?

Comment: KSH version: sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-06-21

Comment: Linux version : Red Hat  6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Gnu or recent versions of date, this works.

```
date -dlast-sunday +%d%m%y

date -dnext-saturday +%d%m%y
```

Use Perl on Solaris because date command does not support this.

```
perl -MPOSIX -e '@DateComponents = localtime; print strftime "%d%m%y", localtime time - 86400*(($DateComponents[6]))' 

perl -MPOSIX -e '@DateComponents = localtime; print strftime "%d%m%y", localtime time + 86400*(6-($DateComponents[6]))'
```

Comment: it is working on Linux. But not on Solaris (ksh version: sh (AT&T Research) 93u 2011-02-08)

Comment: Simplified the Perl expression a bit